# Paw: The value of a cookie changes after a request has been sent

Tags: paw-app

I'm trying to send a request with a session cookie, but when the request is sent the value for that cookie changes.

Here is how the cookie looks:

[image]

Here is how it looks after the request has been sent:
[image: After the request]

What is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer to this question. The only reason I see for the cookie to change is if the server sends back a `Set-Cookie` header in the response.

Paw will behave like web browsers by sending by default a `Cookie` header with the cookies stored for this domain, and will store new cookies when the server sends back a `Set-Cookie` header.

You can see all cookies stored in Paw by going to the left panel > Sessions > Manage:

[image: Manage Cookies in Paw]

Also, please note that you have the ability to disable cookie sending and/or cookie saving for each request in the Request > Options tab:

[image: Disable cookie save or save in Paw]